# Big blank space after header when using itmize in 2 pages in Latex

Tags: header, latex, listings

I'm trying to make a document in latex using a table as a header, but everytime I use an itemize or enumerate longer than 1 page, the 2nd page has a big blank space between the header and the listing.

Can you help me identifying the problem? Any comments would be appreciated.

PS I found it really difficult to make tables in latex, so I used a table latex generator.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{vmargin}  
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{lastpage}  

\usepackage{blindtext}  


\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}  


\setmarginsrb{2.5 cm}{1.5 cm}{2.5 cm}{2.5 cm}{3.6cm}{0.0 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}  
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\fancyhead{} %% clear out all headers  
\fancyhead[C]{%  
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%  
\begin{tabular}{lllll}  
\cline{1-4}  
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{{\includegraphics[width = 2cm,height=0.8cm]{example-image-duck}}} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Name of document}                                   & \multicolumn{1}  {c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Thingies}} &  \\ \cline{2-3}  
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Code of document} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Pag 1 of 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                          &  \\ \cline{1-4}  
                                            &                                       &                                   &                                                &  \\  
                                            &                                       &                                   &                                                &   
\end{tabular}%  
}  
}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------  
\begin{document}  
\begin{titlepage}  
\pagenumbering{gobble}  
%Titel Page  
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}



\section{Section1}
   \blindtext

\section{Section2}
    \blindtext 
\section{Enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
    \end{enumerate}/
\end{document}
```

[image: Big blank space after header when listing continues in a new page.]

[image: Blank space in header using example image]

Comment: That's not the result I get, can you show your .log file? Also your headheight is toooooo small. A warning should tell you how much you need to increase it

Comment: You are correct, the log file says that my headheight is 28.45 pt and it should be at least 90.05 pt. 
Then it says: 

Overfull \vbox (8.05214pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem using `example-image` instead of your one to which we don't have access?

Comment: Absolutely. But I get pretty much the same result, I added the horizontal line of the header, I increased the header height to 100 pt. and reduced the headsep to 0. But I still get a blank space. I added the link of the picture [2] at the end of the code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the additional space comes from the two extra rows at the bottom of the table. There is also an additional column with can be removed as well together with all the unnecessary multicolumns this dreadful table generator inserted.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{vmargin}  
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{lastpage}  

\usepackage{blindtext}  


\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}  


\setmarginsrb{2.5 cm}{1.5 cm}{2.5 cm}{2.5 cm}{3.6cm}{0.0 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}  
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\fancyhead{} %% clear out all headers  
\fancyhead[C]{%  
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%  
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}  
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width = 2cm,height=0.8cm]{example-image-duck}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Name of document} & \multirow{2}{*}{Thingies} \\
\cline{2-3}  
& Code of document & Pag 1 of 2 & \\
\hline   
\end{tabular}%  
}  
}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------  
\begin{document}  
\begin{titlepage}  
\pagenumbering{gobble}  
%Titel Page  
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}



\section{Section1}
   \blindtext

\section{Section2}
    \blindtext 
\section{Enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph  
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
        \item Short paragraph
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!, I've been trying to work with tables more often but I get really confused. I still have lots of reading to do.

Comment: @Ziknich Once you understand the basic mechanism, tables are really not that complicate. For a short intro, see e.g. https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08 (and whatever you do, don't try to understand the code your table generator gives you, that's awful code :) )